# Overlaying Scrollbar Similar to Spotify (Web) Using CSS and/or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

---

**EDITS (4th March, 2024):**

1. I have rephrased my question to get rid of unnecessary code and wordings. I believe it's clearer and easier to read.
2. **I have been made aware that Spotify's scrollbar was constructed with javascript**

---

---

I would like to make a scrollbar that has these two (2) characteristics:

1. Overlays over the content of the div
2. Has a transparent Scrollbar-track

In the previous years, using "background: transparent" worked "overflow: overlay" worked **but it is now deprecated**.

I have researched about alternative methods and gone through different posts, blogs and even questions on this platform all to no avail.

While using Spotify, I noticed their scrollbar was customized. It appeared to have a transparent scrollbar-track which was what I wanted.

This is the image of the Spotify scrollbar

[Image of This is the image of the Spotify Scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPDpQ.png)

I added a snippet to display what I am trying to achieve.
In the snippet I created three "child" divs; with different background colors. They are all children of div named "parent" which has a scrollbar.

**Transparency effect was achieved** but I couldn't get the scrollbar to overlay the "child" divs in the "parent" div.

I would appreciate any advice on how to achieve this overlaying effect with:

1. either CSS alone
2. OR with javascript included.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #a5393900;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  width: 5px;
  background: #f2f2f282;
  background: #f2f2f28f;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* ---- > depracated <-------- */
  overflow: overlay;
}


/* ----- House div needed to center the Parent ------ */

.house {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* --- Parent ----- */

.parent {
  width: 450px;
  height: 450px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ff00ff, #16dc7c);
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


/* ----- CHildren (All) ---- */

.child {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  /* width: 100%; */
  height: 200px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 65px 0px 60px;
  z-index: 10;
}


/* ----- First child ------ */

.child.ch1 {
  background-color: #264cb3;
}


/* ---- Second Child ----- */

.child.ch2 {
  background-color: #8728a7;
}


/* ---- Third Child ---- */

.child.ch3 {
  background-color: #ad9521;
}
```

```html
<div class="house">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child ch1">
      The scrollbar should overlay this div
    </div>
    <div class="child ch2">
      The scrollbar should overlay this div
    </div>
    <div class="child ch3">
      The scrollbar should overlay this div
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It will be great if you will create a demo or fiddle where we can see the issue in action and can help you.

Comment: @Leothelion 
Hey sorry for the late reply, it's my first question so it took me a while to learn how to add snippets but it's finally here.

Comment: @BennnySuun The spotify scrollbar is indeed custom. https://imgur.com/a/s1LYfQu

Answer (score 0):

Spotify is indeed using a custom scrollbar as you can see [here](https://i.imgur.com/W1rhwhg.png). If you want to achieve something like that, you will require Javascript to achieve the same.

Here is an alternative approach you can use using pure HTML and CSS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    body {
      overflow: overlay;
    }

    #main-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    #wrapper {
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      padding: 4px;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to top, blue, purple);
      border-radius: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    #box {
      width: 100%;
      height: 800px;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.507);
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background: transparent;
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="main-container">
        <div id="box">Here is my content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thx, I am getting the transparency but overflow: overlay is depracted so the overlay doesnt work

Comment: @BennnySuun I have updated the code to resolve your issue. As overlay is deprecated so I have tried to fix it using a trick to have a wrapper around the main element that will prevent the scrollbar to overflow. Let me know if this is what you are expecting

Comment: It's giving the transparency which's a plus but its not actually overlaying the content. What I hoped to get was the scrollbar to overlay the content inside the div.

I will update my question since I've already achieved the transparency effect.